# Таск gulp file include

Tags: gulp

Хочу чтобы в index.html можно было инклудить блоки. Например так:

```
@@include('_include/page_head.html')
```

И чтобы файл с блоками оставался в папке разработки и отслеживался в таске watch
А вот мои таски

```
 gulp.task('fileinclude', function() {
 gulp.src('src/_include/*.html')
.pipe(fileinclude({
  prefix: '@@',
  basepath: '@file'
}))
.pipe(concat('page.html'))
.pipe(gulp.dest('src/')); //выгружаем файл
});

gulp.task('watch',['browser-sync', 'fileinclude', 'less', 'scripts'], function() {//
gulp.watch('src/less/**/*.less', ['less']); 
 gulp.watch('src/*.html', browserSync.reload);
  gulp.watch('src/js/**/*.js', browserSync.reload);    
});
```

Comment: https://pugjs.org/language/includes.html

Answer (score -1):

Используйте для вашей затеи [PugJS](https://pugjs.org/language/includes.html). Он не только позволяет делать `include`, но и позволяет не писать закрывающие теги, использовать переменные. А ещё у него есть `extends` – наследование, где потомок может переопределять блоки предка.

Простой пример архитектуры разметки на Pug:

```
doctype html

//- Global variables
block vars

//- Template
html(lang="ru")
    include ../partials/head

    body

        //- Content
        include ../partials/header

        main(role='main')
            block content

        include ../partials/footer

        //- Scripts
        script(async type='text/javascript' src='js/script.js')
```